# How to create a mount --bind when root does not have permission to access the source directory?

Tags: permissions, nfs, bind-mount

While trying to create a test environment using `mount --bind` I was surprised to find that it sometimes fails with permissions errors because `root` cannot access the source directory. This only appears to affect NFS file-systems.

Is there a way to `mount --bind` a directory which `root` cannot access? Perhaps by inode number directly?

### Example

I have an NFS mount which the ordinary `vagrant:vagrant` user can access fully:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/tmp$ find nfs_mount/ -ls
     4375      4 drwxr-xr-x   3 vagrant  vagrant      4096 Mar 20 21:28 nfs_mount/
   257090      4 drwxr-xr-x   3 vagrant  vagrant      4096 Mar 20 21:28 nfs_mount/source
   257091      4 drwx------   3 vagrant  vagrant      4096 Mar 20 21:28 nfs_mount/source/path
   257092      4 drwx------   3 vagrant  vagrant      4096 Mar 20 21:28 nfs_mount/source/path/is
   257093      4 drwx------   2 vagrant  vagrant      4096 Mar 20 21:28 nfs_mount/source/path/is/here
```

... but `root:root` cannot:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/tmp$ sudo find nfs_mount/ -ls
     4375      4 drwxr-xr-x   3 vagrant  vagrant      4096 Mar 20 21:28 nfs_mount/
   257090      4 drwxr-xr-x   3 vagrant  vagrant      4096 Mar 20 21:28 nfs_mount/source
   257091      4 drwx------   3 vagrant  vagrant      4096 Mar 20 21:28 nfs_mount/source/path
find: ‘nfs_mount/source/path’: Permission denied
```

If I attempt to `mount --bind` it fails:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/tmp$ mkdir /tmp/bindtarget

vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/tmp$ sudo mount --bind /tmp/nfs_mount/source/path/is/here/ /tmp/bindtarget/
mount: mount /tmp/nfs_mount/source/path/is/here/ on /tmp/bindtarget failed: Permission denied
```

The NFS mount at `/tmp/nfs_mount` is provided by `localhost:/srv`, and if I go directly to the source file-system the directory permissions don't pose a problem:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/tmp$ sudo mount --bind /srv/source/path/is/here/ /tmp/bindtarget/

vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/tmp$ findmnt /tmp/bindtarget
TARGET          SOURCE                              FSTYPE OPTIONS
/tmp/bindtarget /dev/sda1[/srv/source/path/is/here] ext4   rw,relatime,data=ordered
```

NFS setup in case it matters:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/tmp$ showmount -e localhost
Export list for localhost:
/srv *

vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/tmp$ cat /etc/exports
/srv/       *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

### Environment

- Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial64)
- Linux ubuntu-xenial 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that doing any mount in `/tmp` is hazardous, because some cleaning task might suddenly decide to do its work in `/tmp` and not care about mountpoints, thus wiping old files not actually belonging to `/tmp`. That said I'll use the `/tmp` examples from OP.

---

method 1:

If you're in full control of the NFS environment, just add the `no_root_squash` option to the export options: this will prevent the root user client to be mapped as nobody on the server and losing rights.

---

method2:

Else, here's a relatively simple solution, the one you're looking for, in the same vein as accessing a still-in-use deleted file: using /proc

For simplicity here, requires two terminals:

user terminal:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/tmp$ cd /tmp/nfs_mount/source/path/is/here/
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/tmp/nfs_mount/source/path/is/here$ echo $$
12345
```

root terminal: root can get a reference to the wanted directory, still unreadable, but mountable:

```
# ls -l /proc/12345/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Mar 21 01:18 /proc/12345/cwd -> /tmp/nfs_mount/source/path/is/here
# ls -l /proc/12345/cwd/
ls: cannot open directory '/proc/12345/cwd/': Permission denied

# mount --bind /proc/12345/cwd /tmp/bindtarget
# ls /tmp/bindtarget
ls: cannot open directory '/tmp/bindtarget': Permission denied
```

That's it.

Comment: That's a beautiful work-around, thank you! (Also a very good point about using `/tmp`, I hadn't considered tmpwatch et al)

Comment: this works the other way around, too (target unreadable), thank you so much!